# Sign check for NaN value

Tags: c, visual-studio, unix, nan, sign

My program during calculation can generate `nan` or `-nan` values.
I check if the values are `nan`/`-nan` using `isnan` method.

I also have to distinguish if the nan value is positive or negative (`nan` or `-nan`). How can I do this?

Added:I need crossplatform solution for WIN and for Unix/Linux

Comment: If it isn't a number ... does it make sense determining "its" sign? ????

Comment: @pmg - thre is a diff between nan and -nan

Comment: @Yakov Please tell us the difference. What arithmetic operation ascribes meaning to the sign of the NaN value that it returns?

Comment: @David Heffernan: catan(inf + iNAN) => π/2 + i0; catan(inf - iNAN) => π/2 - i0;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `signbit` from `<math.h>`:

> **Description**
>
> signbit() is a generic macro which can work on all real  floating-point
>   types.   It  returns a nonzero value if the value of x has its sign bit
>   set.
>
> ...
>
> **NaNs and infinities have a sign bit.**

It's apparently part of C99 and POSIX.1-2001, but you could write a macro/function yourself if you don't want to use/conform to either of the two.

Comment: I need it for cross platform system.How can I make it work for Visual Studio?

Comment: @Yakov: Sorry for the late reply. Microsoft might have their own macro/function similar to `signbit`, or you could look up the source to a `signbit` implementation. One example is [here](http://lxr.e2g.org/source/bionic/libm/src/s_signbit.c) with an associated header [here](http://lxr.e2g.org/source/bionic/libm/src/fpmath.h).

Answer (score 2):

Nearly all systems today use either IEEE single or double precision floating-point. So in that case you could (bitwise) convert it to an integer and read the sign-bit.

Here's one approach that uses unions. Although it's not fully standard-compliant, it should still work on nearly all systems.

```
union{
    double f;
    uint64_t i;
} x;

x.f = ... //  Your floating-point value (can be NaN)

//  Check the sign bit.
if ((x.i & 0x8000000000000000ull) == 0){
    //  positive
}else{
    //  negative
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `copysign` function (C99, in `<math.h>`);

```
double sign = copysign(1.0, your_nan);
```

From C99 §7.12.11.1:

> #### Description
>
> The copysign functions produce a value with the magnitude of x and the sign of y.
>   They produce a NaN (with the sign of y) if x is a NaN. On implementations that
>   represent a signed zero but do not treat negative zero consistently in arithmetic
>   operations, the copysign functions regard the sign of zero as positive.
>
> #### Returns
>
> The copysign functions return a value with the magnitude of x and the sign of y.